# Polarity of DC current

Tags: experimental-physics, electric-circuits, electric-current, conventions

Can the polarity of DC current be negative? I mean below the zero like ac shows. If not then why? Please explain. I hope the answer will not be too complicated for a high school boy.

Comment: If I connect a digital ammeter with some polarity and find the displayed value is positive, it is the case that if you connect an identical digital ammeter in series with mine but with opposite polarity, your ammeter will display a negative result and so, yes, the 'polarity' of a DC current can be negative.

Comment: So it depends on the observation and not on the current. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When analyzing a circuit, you'll define a reference direction for the current through each element.

For example, you say "the reference direction for current through this resistor is from left to right". Then if the actual current flowing is left to right, you call that a positive current. If the actual current is flowing right to left, you call that a negative current.

So yes, after defining a reference direction, DC current can be either positive or negative.